# HTTP handlers and javascript bundling in VS 2012

Tags: javascript, asp.net, localization, httphandler, bundling-and-minification

I am currently trying to setup a project to implement localization on javascript files (as described [here](http://madskristensen.net/post/Localize-text-in-JavaScript-files-in-ASPNET.aspx)) but at the same time I'd like to bundle and minify the javascript in the project. I followed a tutorial on bundling and minification [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vs11trainingcourse_aspnetandvisualstudio_topic5#_Toc319053054)

I have been able to get both working separately, but when I try to get them working together I cannot get the localisation working properly. I think this is because bundling creates it's own route handling for the bundled/minified javascript it generates, so the httpHandler I have defined in the webconfig gets ignored. I keep getting javascript errors saying "CustomTranslate is not defined".

I am trying to do this because we are building a number of controls using ExtJS, but we need to be able to apply localisation to those controls. Any help/ideas on how I can get them to work together would be appreciated.

I am **not** using MVC, but doing this in asp.net in Visual Studio 2012.

Here is my code:

BundleConfig.cs

```
namespace TranslationTest
{
    public class BundleConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
        {
            //default bundles addeed here...

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/ExtJS.axd").Include("~/Scripts/ExtJS/ext-all.js", "~/Scripts/ExtJS/TestForm.js"));

        }
    }
}
```

web.config:

```
<globalization uiCulture="auto" />
<httpHandlers>
  <add verb="*" path="/bundles/ExtJS.axd" type="TranslationTest.ScriptTranslator, TranslationTest" />
</httpHandlers>
```

Default.aspx

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="TranslationTest._Default" %>

<asp:Content runat="server" ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <script src="/bundles/ExtJS.axd"></script>
</asp:Content>
```

TestForm.js:

```
Ext.require([
       'Ext.form.*',
       'Ext.layout.container.Column',
       'Ext.tab.Panel'
]);

Ext.onReady(function () {

    Ext.QuickTips.init();

    var bd = Ext.getBody();

    bd.createChild({ tag: 'h2', html: 'Form 1' });


    var simple = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
        url: 'save-form.php',
        frame: true,
        title: 'Simple Form',
        bodyStyle: 'padding:5px 5px 0',
        width: 350,
        fieldDefaults: {
            msgTarget: 'side',
            labelWidth: 75
        },
        defaultType: 'textfield',
        defaults: {
            anchor: '100%'
        },

        items: [{
            fieldLabel: CustomTranslate(FirstName),
            name: 'first',
            allowBlank: false
        }, {
            fieldLabel: CustomTranslate(LastName),
            name: 'last'
        }, {
            fieldLabel: CustomTranslate(Company),
            name: 'company'
        }, {
            fieldLabel: CustomTranslate(Email),
            name: 'email',
            vtype: 'email'
        }, {
            xtype: 'timefield',
            fieldLabel: CustomTranslate(Time),
            name: 'time',
            minValue: '8:00am',
            maxValue: '6:00pm'
        }],

        buttons: [{
            text: CustomTranslate(Save)
        }, {
            text: CustomTranslate(Cancel)
        }]
    });

    simple.render(document.body);


});
```

Currently the FirstName, LastName, etc are all stored in resource files, as in the linked example above.

ScriptTranslator.cs

```
namespace TranslationTest
{
    public class ScriptTranslator : IHttpHandler
    {
        #region IHttpHandler Members

        public bool IsReusable
        {
            get { return false; }
        }

        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            string relativePath = context.Request.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath.Replace(".axd", string.Empty);
            string absolutePath = context.Server.MapPath(relativePath);
            string script = ReadFile(absolutePath);
            string translated = TranslateScript(script);

            context.Response.Write(translated);

            Compress(context);
            SetHeadersAndCache(absolutePath, context);
        }

        #endregion

        private void SetHeadersAndCache(string file, HttpContext context)
        {
            context.Response.AddFileDependency(file);
            context.Response.Cache.VaryByHeaders["Accept-Language"] = true;
            context.Response.Cache.VaryByHeaders["Accept-Encoding"] = true;
            context.Response.Cache.SetLastModifiedFromFileDependencies();
            context.Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now.AddDays(7));
            context.Response.Cache.SetValidUntilExpires(true);
            context.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Public);
        }

        #region Localization

        private static Regex REGEX = new Regex(@"CustomTranslate\(([^\))]*)\)", RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.Compiled);

        private string TranslateScript(string text)
        {
            MatchCollection matches = REGEX.Matches(text);
            ResourceManager manager = new ResourceManager(typeof(TranslationTest.App_GlobalResources.text));

            foreach (Match match in matches)
            {
                object obj = manager.GetObject(match.Groups[1].Value);
                if (obj != null)
                {
                    text = text.Replace(match.Value, CleanText(obj.ToString()));
                }
            }
            return text;
        }

        private static string CleanText(string text)
        {
            text = text.Replace("'", "\\'");
            text = text.Replace("\\", "\\\\");
            return text;
        }

        private static string ReadFile(string absolutePath)
        {
            if (File.Exists(absolutePath))
            {
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(absolutePath))
                {
                    return reader.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        #endregion

        #region Compression

        private const string GZIP = "gzip";
        private const string DEFLATE = "deflate";

        private static void Compress(HttpContext context)
        {
            if (IsEncodingAccepted(DEFLATE, context))
            {
                context.Response.Filter = new DeflateStream(context.Response.Filter, CompressionMode.Compress);
                SetEncoding(DEFLATE, context);
            }
            else if (IsEncodingAccepted(GZIP, context))
            {
                context.Response.Filter = new GZipStream(context.Response.Filter, CompressionMode.Compress);
                SetEncoding(GZIP, context);
            }
        }

        private static bool IsEncodingAccepted(string encoding, HttpContext context)
        {
            return context.Request.Headers["Accept-encoding"] != null && context.Request.Headers["Accept-encoding"].Contains(encoding);
        }

        private static void SetEncoding(string encoding, HttpContext context)
        {
            context.Response.AppendHeader("Content-encoding", encoding);
        }

        #endregion

    }
}
```

global.asax.cs

```
namespace TranslationTest
{
    public class Global : HttpApplication
    {
        void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Microsoft.Web.Optimization.BundleTable.Bundles.EnableDefaultBundles();

            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(System.Web.Optimization.BundleTable.Bundles);
            AuthConfig.RegisterOpenAuth();
        }
    }
}
```

I hope I've covered everything, but please let me know if there's anything missing. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Btw, it's probably also worth mentioning that I also tried making my script translator implement IRouteHandler too, but didn't have much luck going down that road either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, I've set up everything in your example and I've got it to work but you need to use the IBundleTransform interface. The details of everything I did are posted below..

I had to create a class to handle the bundle transformation (i.e the translation) instead of allowing the default behaviour.

```
public class JsLocalizationTransform : IBundleTransform
    {
        public JsLocalizationTransform(){}

        #region IBundleTransform Members

        public void Process(BundleContext context, BundleResponse response)
        {
            string translated = TranslateScript(response.Content);

            response.Content = translated;
        }

        #endregion

        #region Localization

        private static Regex REGEX = new Regex(@"CustomTranslate\(([^\))]*)\)", RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.Compiled);

        private string TranslateScript(string text)
        {
            MatchCollection matches = REGEX.Matches(text);
            ResourceManager manager = new ResourceManager(typeof(TranslationTest.App_GlobalResources.text));

            foreach (Match match in matches)
            {
                object obj = manager.GetObject(match.Groups[1].Value);
                if (obj != null)
                {
                    text = text.Replace(match.Value, CleanText(obj.ToString()));
                }
            }

            return text;
        }

        private static string CleanText(string text)
        {
            //text = text.Replace("'", "\\'");
            text = text.Replace("\\", "\\\\");

            return text;
        }
        #endregion

    }
```

Then in BundleConfig.RegisterBundles method you need to create and add the bundle like this:

```
var extjsBundle = new Bundle("~/bundles/ExtJS").Include("~/Scripts/ExtJS/ext-all.js", "~/Scripts/ExtJS/TestForm.js");
    extjsBundle.Transforms.Clear();
    extjsBundle.Transforms.Add(new JsLocalizationTransform());
    extjsBundle.Transforms.Add(new JsMinify());
    bundles.Add(extjsBundle);
```

I could then remove the `HttpHandler` from web.config as that gets configured automatically through the bundler. I also had to make some changes to the Application_Start method in global.asax.cs

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Microsoft.Web.Optimization.BundleTable.Bundles.EnableDefaultBundles(); 
            BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true; //Added this line..
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(System.Web.Optimization.BundleTable.Bundles);
            AuthConfig.RegisterOpenAuth();
        }
```

Because the `JSLocalisationTransform` class is handling the bundle transformation and translation, I completely removed the `ScriptTranslator` class.

Hope that helps.

Comment: How do you handle the cache and the language change?